# Is Putting an HTML Heading Tag in a Paragraph Tag Going to Work?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a line of code, and I have tried putting an HTML image tag inside a paragraph tag, and that works. But I tried the same thing for a pair of heading tags inside, but it doesn't work. Help? I need to add an id to the heading so I can edit the heading id (bunny-title) above in CSS, so I can't just declare it like the "STORE TEXT!!!" without the heading tags.

```
    <p  class = "tab-text" id = "store">

        STORE TEXT!!! 

        <img id="bunny" src="http://sciencenordic.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/620x/rabbit_0.jpg" width="230">

        <h3 id="bunny-title">Little Bunny!</h3>

         </p>
```

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/www139/yLwufk2h/1/

Comment: The heading shouldn't be inside <p> tags

Answer (score 0):

A paragraph tag should not contain any heading tags. A paragraph should only contain phrasing content.

> Phrasing Content Consists of phrasing elements intermixed with normal
>   character data. [w3 reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#phrasing-content)

Phrasing elements are:

> a or em or strong or small or mark or abbr or dfn or i or b or s or u
>   or code or var or samp or kbd or sup or sub or q or cite or span or
>   bdo or bdi or br or wbr or ins or del or img or embed or object or
>   iframe or map or area or script or noscript or ruby or video or audio
>   or input or textarea or select or button or label or output or
>   datalist or keygen or progress or command or canvas or time or meter. [w3 reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing)

You can see heading tags are not mentioned in the above list.

For valid html you want your html to look like this:

```
<h3 id="bunny-title">Little Bunny!</h3>
<p class = "tab-text" id = "store">
    STORE TEXT!!! 
    <img id="bunny" src="http://sciencenordic.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/620x/rabbit_0.jpg" width="230">
</p>
```

Generally a header will come before a paragraph, like in a book. However this isn't mandatory in an html document.